# Handle Sorted Group in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have an Sorted input like this:
(Sorted in order A,B,C )

A - B - C - D        --> Fields

1 - 1 - 1 - 123

1 - 1 - 1 - 345

1 - 1 - 2 - 345

1 - 2 - 1 - 122

1 - 2 - 2 - 232

1 - 3 - 5 - 764

2 - 1 - 4 - 234

2 - 2 - 1 - 453

2 - 2 - 3 - 234

2 - 3 - 3 - 754

3 - 1 - 5 - 432

I want to separate the records of each group. 
For instance,

1 - 1 - 1 - 123

1 - 1 - 1 - 345
is a group.

Records with same A, B and C values fall in same group.

What should be the best option to handle this?

Note: Java 1.6

Comment: The "best option" depends on how you want to *use* the data.

Comment: @Bathsheba I will add the field D values of each group and some avg like manipulation. And then, concat all values like ABCD.. 111xyz..

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @TomCammann I'm doing a while loop with values of first group.. then on exiting.. updating the values and doing the same while loop.. I know this is not the right way.. Hence.. looking for some suggestion to do the right way

Comment: Post the code! We can suggest what improvements you can make.,

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<List<Integer>, List<Integer>>
```

The first list is the identifier of the group (in your example it will be [1,1,1], and the second list can be put all values for the given group (in your example it will be [123,345].

a very pseudo code to fill your groups:

```
    Map<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> groups;

    for (Row row : rows){
        List identifier = new ArrayList();
        identifier.add(row.A);
        identifier.add(row.B);
        identifier.add(row.C);

        groups.get(identifier).add(row.D);

    }
```

This seems pretty flexible, you can easily modify columns that are considered as identifiers, you can easily go throught all groups and do something with their lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you think your sorted input as a `List<Map<String, Object>` (could be, no?)

something like

```
tobegrouped = [{A=1, B=1, C=1, D=1111},{A=1, B=1, C=1, D=1112}, {A=1, B=2, C=1, D=1211}]
```

And then think to group it by A, B, C (like in sql), you will have a map of map of map of list of map

```
grouped = {1={1={1=[{D=111, A=1, B=1, C=1}, {D=1111, A=1, B=1, C=1}], 2=[{D=112, A=1, B=1, C=2}]}, 2={1=[{D=121, A=1, B=2, C=1}]}}}
```

**EDIT** Better view of the grouped elements

```
{
    1: {
        1: {
            1: [{
                D: 111,
                A: 1,
                B: 1,
                C: 1
            },
            {
                D: 1111,
                A: 1,
                B: 1,
                C: 1
            }],
            2: [{
                D: 112,
                A: 1,
                B: 1,
                C: 2
            }]
        },
        2: {
            1: [{
                D: 121,
                A: 1,
                B: 2,
                C: 1
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can get the group's elements by call grouped.get("A").get("B").get("C") (in the real world you have to cast).

Here an example of a group by function over a List of Map (I used it to group rows from database).
This is general so you can specilize as you need.

```
public static Map<String, Object> groupby(List<? extends Map<String, Object>> tobegrouped, String...groupby) {
    if (groupby == null || groupby.length == 0) {
        for (String firstkey : tobegrouped.get(0).keySet()) {
            groupby = new String[1];
            groupby[0] = firstkey;
            break;
        }
    }
    Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> themap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>();
    for (Map<String, Object> arow : tobegrouped) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> l = themap.get(arow.get(groupby[0]).toString());
        if (l == null) {
            themap.put(arow.get(groupby[0]).toString(), new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>());
        }
        themap.get(arow.get(groupby[0]).toString()).add(arow);
    }

    if (groupby.length > 1) {
        for (Entry<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> grouped : themap.entrySet()) {
            String[] _groupby = new String[groupby.length - 1];
            for (int i = 1; i < groupby.length; i++) {
                _groupby[i-1] = groupby[i];
            }
            Map<String, Object> _grouped = MyUtils.groupby(grouped.getValue(), _groupby);
            result.put(grouped.getKey(), _grouped);
        }
    } else {
        for (Entry<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> grouped : themap.entrySet()) {
            result.put(grouped.getKey(), grouped.getValue());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```